# Can't seem to stretch an image to 100% of the webpage

Tags: html, css, width

I'm currently trying to create a simple webpage for the http://www.code.org Computer Science week!

I'm trying to create an image based background for my navigation bar at the top of the page.

This is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Welcome</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="css/text" href="CSstylesheet.css"
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <img src="binarybanner.png" id="bannerimg" />
      </div>
      <div class="h3setup">
         <a href="">
            <h3 id="GI">General Information</h3>
         </a>
         <a href="">
            <h3 id="BC">Benefits to Coding</h3>
         </a>
         <a href="">
            <h3 id="CT">Coding Types</h3>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div>
         <img src="siteMapButton.png" id="siteMapButton"/>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
h3 {
    display: inline;
}
div.h3setup {
    left: 195px;
    top: 145px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    width: 100%
}
div.h3setup a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#GI {
    border: 2px solid #7FFF00;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background: black;
    padding: 6px;
    color: #7FFF00;
}
#GI:hover {
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #99FF66;
}
#BC {
    border: 2px solid #7FFF00;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background: black;
    padding: 6px;
    color: #7FFF00;
}
#BC:hover {
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #99FF66;
}
#CT {
    border: 2px solid #7FFF00;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background: black;
    padding: 6px;
    color: #7FFF00;
}
#CT:hover {
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #99FF66;
}
#bannerimg {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%
    display: inline;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
#siteMapButton {
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Your `<link />` tag is malformed. You haven't closed it. That might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a simi-colon after `width: 100%` in your css.  In jsfiddle that fixed the problem.

Comment: Everything is fixed. Your comment, as well as JoshC's comment have relieved the issue. I think I tried adding the semi-colon and I didn't get the same results. I don't know, it's most likely just me. Thanks for the help! I can't wait to get this thing submitted! :D